# Losing connection with wireless headset since restoring computer

Tags: headphones, macos

I have a [Logitech Wireless Gaming Headset G930](http://support.logitech.com/product/wireless-gaming-headset-g930) connected to my Macbook Air which loses the connection to the headset every 5-15 minutes.

The headset is now several months old and I haven't had any problems until a few weeks back. Around the same time I restored my computer with first installing Yosemite and then a week later installing the El Capitan public beta (currently on Public Beta 3, 15A243d).

When the headset loses its connection I can still see the headset in the OS X speaker selector, since the USB dongle is connected. I can then reconnect the headset by unplugging and plugging back in the USB dongle.

Could El Capitan be the problem or could I have missed installing some software after restoring my computer?

---

### Edit 2015-08-24

After updating to Public Beta 5 the connection have been significantly  better, only disconnecting 1 or 2 times *per day*

Comment: Did you experience the issue while it was running on Yosemite as well, or only after you upgraded to El Capitan?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think so, yes

Comment: Are you using them under bootcamp? The link you provided shows them to only be compatible with Windows. Is it possible that Apple had a driver for them that was not ported over to El Cap?

Comment: @AMR No, I'm using them in OS X

Comment: This is a stretch, but it your MBA has a USB 3 port and Apple has made changes to their driver to support USB 3.1 and USB C, that might be interfering with the connectivity of your device. On Logitech's forums, a support specialist responded to using the Headset on Mac that it needed to be connected via USB 2... Maybe Apple messed up something in backwards compatibility.

Comment: Interesting, yes it is a USB 3 port its connected to. Do you have a link to the forum thread?

Answer (score 1):

El Capitan is beta software, so there's going to be a lot of bugs, that's the idea of a public beta: let users find and report bugs before the software is released to the mainstream. So, unfortunately, you may have to wait until October when El Capitan comes out for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone. It's actually something wrong with the public beta of El Capitan.

See [this forum post.](https://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/MX-Master-OSX-El-Capitan-Incompatible/td-p/1412449#link_144)